# Windows Authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

I've just watched a simple tutorial about Windows Authentication in ASP.NET MVC, and it looks really simple to use, but I'm getting some strange problems testing it. What I've done:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
...
```

In "Project Properties" I've changed Anonymous Authentication to disabled and Windows Authentication to enabled.

Now when I put an Authorize attribute on a method, and it works but not on a whole HomeController and Index action.

```
[Authorize(Users = @"MACHINENAME\Simple")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
```

When I enter localhost/Home/About it asks for login/password, and it works fine. When I move to localhost/Home/Contant and back to Home/About it dosen't want password again, but after I'm logged in and I go back to localhost/Home/Index it's required to give a login/password again on Home/About. Can someone explain why is it so ?

And the other thing is, that when I put an Authorize attribute on a whole HomeController, it wants a login/password but when I enter them it does not log me in. The same situation happens on HomeController/Index action.

Comment: you need to allow only "Machinename\Simple" to access the action?

Comment: I want to make it work for windows group that user has, and I want to understand why it's not allowing me to enter with right login/password combination, when I put [Authorize] attribute on HomeController, action Index